# How to add CSS for hover element without hiding the original element

Tags: css

I am trying to create a tool tip on my buttons. I have written the following code, it gives a little circle on mouse hover, but it disappears the original circle. Is there any way that I can hold the big Circle on mouse hover and display the little circle?

```
<style>

    #item
    {
        background-color: red;
        border-radius:50%;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;

        }

    #item:hover
    {
        background-color:black;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:relative;
        top:0px;    

        }   


</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id ="item">

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes, you could do this with a pseudoelement.

Answer (score 3):

Solution  : [solution is here](http://jsfiddle.net/z894g/)

html

```
<div id ="item">
   <div id ="item2">
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#item
{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;

    }

#item2
{
    background-color:black;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:relative;
display:none;
    top:0px;    

    }   
 #item:hover > #item2
{
    display:block;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution. Watch out for [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/)

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/H7pWC/1/)

HTML

```
<div id ="item">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#item {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    top:50px;
}
#item:hover:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display: block;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

---

Above is the simplest way, but seeing as you will display text in your tooltip. Something like this may be more appropriate.

[Fiddle for this!](http://jsfiddle.net/H7pWC/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="item">
    <div>This is my tooltip</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#item {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position: relative;
}
#item div {
    display: none;
}
#item:hover div {
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    bottom: -40px;
    right: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/g3yW9/

```
$(function(){
    $('#item').hover(function(){
        $('#tooltip').fadeIn(200);
    },function(){
        $('#tooltip').fadeOut(200);
    });
});
```